# R increment column value based on character match in another column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have an array of data that can be modelled roughly as follows:

```
x=data.frame(c(2,2,2),c(3,4,6),c(3,4,6), c("x/-","x/x","-/x"))
names(x)=c("A","B","C","D")
```

I wish to change the values of B to (C + 1) if **only** the first character in D is -.

I have tried using the following and iterating over the rows:

```
if(substring(x$D, 1,1) == "-") 
{
  x$B <- x$C + 1       
}
```

However this method does not seem to work. Is there a way to do this using sapply?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ifelse` and `within`

```
within(x, B <- ifelse(substr(D, 1, 1) == "-", C + 1, B))
#   A B C   D
# 1 2 3 3 x/-
# 2 2 4 4 x/x
# 3 2 7 6 -/x
```

Or instead of `substr`, you could use `grepl`

```
within(x, B <- ifelse(grepl("^[-]", D), C + 1, B))
#   A B C   D
# 1 2 3 3 x/-
# 2 2 4 4 x/x
# 3 2 7 6 -/x
```

Answer (score 1):

`data.table` solution.

```
require(data.table)

x <- data.table(c(2,2,2), c(3,4,6), c(3,4,6), c("x/-","x/x","-/x"))
setnames(x, c("A","B","C","D"))

x[grepl("^[-]", D), B := C + 1]
```